# How to convert SelectMany to Async LINQ Call

Tags: c#, linq

How would I conver the following to a Async Linq call. I know LINQ doesn't work the best with Async calls and SelectMany directly will not work. I've tried a number of things with now luck. Thanks.

How would I convert this to an ASYNC call?

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }  
    // other props
}
You can get children of one item using:

List<Foo> GetChildren(List<Foo> foos, int id)
{
    return foos
        .Where(x => x.ParentId == id)
        .Union(foos.Where(x => x.ParentId == id)
            .SelectMany(y => GetChildren(foos, y.Id))
        ).ToList();
}
For ex.

List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>();

foos.Add(new Foo { Id = 1 });
foos.Add(new Foo { Id = 2, ParentId = 1 });
foos.Add(new Foo { Id = 3, ParentId = 2 });
foos.Add(new Foo { Id = 4 });

GetChild(foos, 1).Dump(); // will give you 2 and 3 (ids)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# async when returning LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643752/c-sharp-async-when-returning-linq)

Comment: Thank you John Wu. I'll check this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> LINQ works perfectly using async-await. I think your misconception is
>   because it is not clear to you when a query is actually performed.

You don't state whether you are working with `Iqueryable` or `IEnumerable`, but the principle remains the same.

There are two kinds of LINQ statements: those that will only change the query, and those that will execute the query.

You can see to which group your (concatenation of) linq statements belongs. If the result is an `IEnumerable<TResult>` or `IQueryable<TResult>`, then only the query is created. it is not executed yet. The database has not been accessed yet (or in case of a file: the contents of the file is not read).

If the result is a `List<TResult>`, one `TResult`, or a `Boolean`, etc, so not an `IEnumerable` then the query is actually executed. Or to be more precise: `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` have been called, the data is actually fetched and put into the result.

Methods of the first group are `Where`, `Select`, 'Union', 'GroupJoin', `GroupBy`, etc.

Methods of the second group are `ToList`, `ToDictionary`, but also `FirstOrDefault` and `Any`. When these functions are called, the database is actually accessed, or the file contents is actually processed, etc.

Methods that change the query are not time consuming. Hence it is not useful to make those functions awaitable. However it is very useful to make querying a database (etc.) awaitable. Therefore you'll find async versions for them. For example you can find methods like [IQueryable.ToListAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220258%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), [IQueryable.ToDictionaryAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions.todictionaryasync(v=vs.113).aspx), [IQueryable.FirstOrDefaultAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn218858(v=vs.113).aspx), and even [IQueryable.AnyAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237197(v=vs.113).aspx)

Back to your query:

```
Task<List<Foo>> GetChildrenAsync(IEnumerable<Foo> foos, int id)
{
   var query = foos.Where(foo => foo.ParentId == id)
       .Union(foos
           .Where(foo => foo.ParentId == id)
           .SelectMany(foo => GetChildren(foos, y.Id));
   // until now only the query has been created.
   // collection foos has not been accessed yet.

   // execute the query:
   var result = await query.ToListAsync();
   return result;
```

}

If you divide your statements in these smaller steps it is easier for you to use your debugger to see when the GetEnumerator is actually called. If desired you can of course change it into one big statement.

By the way, if your input really a List? in that case I'm fairly certain that is is quite useless to make your function awaitable. async-await is only useful if your thread has to wait for another thread or process to finish before it can continue. But that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Thanks. You are right, I did not need to do Async on it because it is in Memory. I do the Async prior when I get all the Foo IEnumerable